# golang Chi router with query params not working

Tags: rest, go, go-chi

I am working on a restful service in golang using chi. I am trying to create a route as below

```
r.Mount("/api/dest", router.NewDestRouter(chi.NewRouter(), destSrv).InitRoutes())

func (dr *DestRouter) InitRoutes() http.Handler {
    dr.router.Post("/{number}/product?version={v}", handlers.HandleProduct(dr.dest))
    return dr.router
}
```

But I try to hit this endpoint via post man I get a 404 not found

```
http://localhost:8345/api/dest/1235abc/product?version=1
```

May I know the issue here?

Comment: Just a guess as I am not a `chi` user, but I assume it doesn't match against query parameters, so leave it out when registering the handler and use `r.URL.Query().Get("version")` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As @mkopriva mentioned, simply use `r.URL.Query().Get("version")` to get the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Met this issue, found status 404, for your situation, only go with `/{number}/product`, do not need to add the content `?version={v}`, chi only match with the path, and then use `r.URL.Query().Get("version")` to get the query parameters, it will work.