# Filtering on golang API using chi router

Tags: go

I'm using GO and chi router trying to create and endpoint filtering a table by status, but when I use the **?** on the URL I'm receiving `404 page not found`.

I am using the following code:

```
r.Get("/table?status={status}", l.Hanlder(tableHandler.GetByStatus))
```

When I remove the **?** it works just well. I can't use it to filter? I can not, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [golang Chi router with query params not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933367/golang-chi-router-with-query-params-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`URLParam`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi#URLParam) or [`URLParamFromCtx`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi#URLParamFromCtx) function to get the value of a query string parameter.

Comment: I am using URLParam, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to remove the `?status={status}` from your route. It should be simply `/table`.

Comment: That was it! I took a little while to come back to you, but it worked, hahaha ty so much!

Comment: You’re welcome. Make sure to accept the answer so that it can help others, too!